# Flutter Error: 'Because xml >=4.4.0 <4.4.1 depends on petitp

Tags: flutter

Because xml >=4.4.0 <4.4.1 depends on petitparser ^3.1.0 and xml >=3.7.0 <4.4.0 depends on petitparser ^3.0.0, xml >=3.7.0 <4.4.1 requires petitparser ^3.0.0.
Running "flutter pub get" in flutterdemoapp...

And because xml >=4.4.1 <5.0.0-nullsafety.1 depends on petitparser ^3.0.0, xml >=3.7.0 <5.0.0-nullsafety.1 requires petitparser ^3.0.0.
Running "flutter pub get" in flutterdemoapp...

And because every version of intl_translation from git depends on petitparser ^4.0.0 and flutter_svg >=0.18.1 <0.20.0-nullsafety.0 depends on xml ^4.2.0, intl_translation from git is incompatible with flutter_svg >=0.18.1 <0.20.0-nullsafety.0.
Running "flutter pub get" in flutterdemoapp...

So, because natrium_wallet_flutter depends on both flutter_svg ^0.19.3 and intl_translation from git, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in flutterdemoapp...

pub get failed (1; So, because flutterdemoapp depends on
both flutter_svg ^0.19.3 and intl_translation from git, version
solving failed.)

Comment: share your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: ...and post the output of `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: M Karimi, I have shared my pubspec.yaml file. Cheers!

Comment: GrahamD - Alright let me do that just now.

Answer (score 0):

```
name: natrium_wallet_flutter
description: Natrium - Fast, Robust & Secure NANO Wallet.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 2.4.2+80

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.99 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # Securley store data in a keystore
  flutter_secure_storage: ^4.1.0

  # Nano core functions
  flutter_nano_ffi: ^2.0.0

  # Shared prefs
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5

  # Flare for animations
  flare_flutter: ^2.0.6

  # Websockets
  web_socket_channel: ^1.0.9

  # Platform-specific build info
  package_info: ^2.0.0

  # Device-specific info
  device_info: ^2.0.0

  # JSON Serialization
  json_annotation: ^3.1.1

  # Localization
  intl: ^0.17.0

  # BigDecimal alternative
  decimal: ^1.0.0

  # Logger
  logger: ^1.0.0

  # Native webview plugin
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.11

  # SQLite
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+3

  # Android/iOS path provider
  path_provider: ^2.0.1

  # TouchID/FaceID
  local_auth: ^1.0.0-nullsafety.3
  # Eventbus
  event_taxi: ^1.0.0

  # SVG
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0

  # QR Codes
  qr_flutter: ^2.0.1 # Generator
  barcode_scan:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/bbedward/flutter_barcode_reader.git
      ref: master

  # Share files
  share:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/bbedward/plugins.git
      path: packages/share
      ref: master

  # File picker
  file_picker: ^3.0.0-nullsafety.0

  # Deep link support
  #uni_links: ^0.2.0
  uni_links:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/bbedward/uni_links.git
      ref: master

  # HTTP client
  http: ^0.12.1

  # Vibrate
  vibrate:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/bbedward/flutter_vibrate.git
      ref: master

  # Toast
  oktoast: ^3.0.0

  # Push notifications
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3

  # Slidable list actions
  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.7

  # Lock helper
  synchronized: ^3.0.0

  # Service provider
  get_it: ^6.0.0

  # Root/Jailbreak detection
  root_checker:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/bbedward/root_checker.git
      ref: master

  # Validation utilities
  validators: 2.0.0

  # Auto resize text widget
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0

  # Avoid keyboard from overlapping text fields
  keyboard_avoider: ^0.1.2

  # Launch external URLs
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2

  # Manta dart implementation
  manta_dart:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/bbedward/manta-dart.git
      ref: master

  devicelocale: ^0.4.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: 1.11.1
  json_serializable: ^3.5.1
  intl_translation:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/bbedward/intl_translation.git
      ref: master

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: NunitoSans
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/NunitoSans-Regular.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: fonts/NunitoSans-ExtraLight.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: fonts/NunitoSans-Light.ttf
          weight: 200
        - asset: fonts/NunitoSans-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: fonts/NunitoSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 800
        - asset: fonts/NunitoSans-ExtraBold.ttf
          weight: 900
    - family: OverpassMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/OverpassMono-Regular.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: fonts/OverpassMono-Light.ttf
          weight: 100
    - family: AppIcons
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/AppIcons.ttf
          weight: 500
    - family: Comfortaa
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Comfortaa-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: fonts/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: fonts/Comfortaa-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
  assets:
    - assets/QR.svg
    - assets/welcome_animation.flr
    - assets/send_animation.flr
    - assets/manta_animation.flr
    - assets/transfer_animation_natriumwalletonly.flr
    - assets/transfer_animation_paperwalletonly.flr
    - assets/searchseedqr_animation_magnifyingglassonly.flr
    - assets/searchseedqr_animation_glassonly.flr
    - assets/searchseedqr_animation_qronly.flr
    - assets/searchseedmanual_animation_magnifyingglassonly.flr
    - assets/searchseedmanual_animation_glassonly.flr
    - assets/searchseedmanual_animation_seedonly.flr
    - assets/threedot_animation.flr
    - assets/offline_animation.flr
    - assets/sharecard_logo.svg
    - assets/transferfunds_illustration_start_natriumwalletonly.svg
    - assets/transferfunds_illustration_start_paperwalletonly.svg
    - assets/transferfunds_illustration_end_natriumwalletonly.svg
    - assets/transferfunds_illustration_end_paperwalletonly.svg
    - assets/pulltosend_animation.flr
    - assets/sheethandle_animation.flr
    - assets/ntr_placeholder_animation.flr

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS D:\Flutter Development\Cry
pto Afritex> flutter doctor 
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter
doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft    Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110], locale   
    en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android
    devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)   
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to      accept the SDK licenses.
      See
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/insta      ll/windows#android-setup for more details.[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find
    Chrome executable at
    .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting
      CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.58.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
PS D:\Flutter Development\Crypto Afritex>
```